# Displaying rows for this week only in PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two dates stored in my database as columns `dtp_s` and `dtp_e` (start, end). These derive from a populated form which the user is made to select a start and end date.

I want to display records from Monday - Sunday of the current week, but my current solution is showing dates from 7 Days before - Today.

```
SELECT id
FROM _records
WHERE
    dtp_s > unix_timestamp(now() - interval 1 week)
    AND userid = ?
ORDER BY dtp_s DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

I have tried to change `now()` to be the value of `strtotime( 'sunday' )` but this then shows no records when one does exist.

Any ideas on how I only show data based on ones that start the same week (Mon - Sun) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Monday of the current week you could use:-

```
select date(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day)
```

To add this into your code:-

```
SELECT id FROM _records 
WHERE dtp_s > date(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day) AND userid = ? 
ORDER BY dtp_s DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at other questions from SO, this can be achieved in SQL rather than mixing PHP `strtotime` values that could be in different timezones if not configured correctly.

```
SELECT id FROM _records
WHERE dtp_s > unix_timestamp(date(now() + interval 6 - weekday(now()) DAY) - interval 1 week)
AND userid = ?
ORDER BY dtp_s DESC
LIMIT 5
```

I am getting only the records for this week displayed.